# Use Jsoup to select an HTML element with no class

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup, selector

Consider an html document like this one

```html
<div>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    ...
    <p class="random_class_name">...</p>
    ...
</div>
```

How could we select all of the `p` elements, but excluding the `p` element with `random_class_name` class?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Elements ps = body.select("p:not(.random_class_name)");
```

You can use the pseudo selector `:not`

If the class name is not known, you still can use a similar expression:

```
Elements ps = body.select("p:not([class])");
```

In the second example I use the attribute selector `[]`, in the first the normal syntax for classes.

See the [Jsoup docu about css selectors](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)

Comment: Sorry if the question was unclear, "random_class_name" is literally an unknown class, not one with that name

Comment: other `p` have no classes?

Comment: see my edit. as long as the other <p> have no class assigned it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlValue);
    Elements pElements = doc.select("p");         
    for (Element element : pElements) {
        String class = element.attr("class");
        if(class == null){
            //.....
        }else{
             //.....
        }
    }
```