# How to get text from div that has no id and class in jSoup Java

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to get text from div tag that has no id and class.

```
<div class="prod-fulfillment-messaging-text">
    <div> This is not found. </div>
</div>
```

I want to fetch "This is not found" text. Can any body help me that how I can fetch it. Thanks!

Comment: You can always fetch the contents of  `<div class="prod-fulfillment-messaging-text">` and then strip the `div` tags from the content.

Comment: Can you please explain it for me?

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440864/use-jsoup-to-select-an-html-element-with-no-class/31440924#31440924

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 String str = doc.getElementsByClass("prod-fulfillment-messaging-text")
  .first().child(0).text();
```

Another option could be:

```
doc.select("div.prod-fulfillment-messaging-text > div:first-child").text();
```

Comment: @Ghulam added another option